# static keyword in Java

Tags: java

```
class A {
    static {
        System.out.println("A-SIB");
    }
    static void test(){
        System.out.println("A-test");
    }
}

class B extends A  {
    static {
        System.out.println("B-SIB");
    }
}

class C  {
    public static void main(String args []){
        B.test();
    }
}
```

When I ran class C, I thought `A-SIB`, `B-SIB` and `A-test` will be printed, but `B-SIB` was not there in the output. Can somebody explain why?

Comment: Before you continue posting, take the time to learn how to format your code in questions.

Comment: `static` methods are not inherited nor can they be overridden.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I didn't learn how to properly format code in question until having a week in SO. For voter to close, this question isn't too broad, it has an specific answer.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza but OP has a static block (not sure if that's intended) which seems to me should be run at the first invocation of `B`.

Comment: But if static methods are not inherited then how did class B can print test method.

Comment: result will be a "B-SIB A-SIB A-test" because JVM load static variables before load class.

Comment: I just ran it (after fixing some compile errors). It prints "A-SIB \n A-test"

Comment: @aliteralmind that's strange behavior...

Comment: dude, result is A-SIB and A-test , and that's why i am asking this question.

Comment: I think that when `B` "inherits" `test()`, that just tells the compiler that when it sees `B.test`, it will treat it the same as `A.test` (since it's a static method).  Therefore, there is no need to load class `B` when `B.test()` is called, because it's just really calling `A.test()`, and no object of type `B` is involved.  However, I don't know the exact rules.

Comment: So why is the `B` static-initializer block not executing? I'm guessing that there's no reason to create a `B` given the execution-path...although that doesn't even really make sense, given only static things are being used.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is actually a good question, with example code and the expected outputs. And I don't even know the answer, I'd have to dig into the JLS.

Comment: Java... Misterious Java... :)

Comment: I mean, it's obvious the classloader isn't loading `B` because in reality nothing in `B` is being used, but I actually didn't know it would do that.

Comment: @Aamir: "But if static methods are not inherited then how did class B can print test method?" There is no overriding of anything in your code. There's a single function in `A` (`test`), and it's not being overridden at all (there's no `test` in `B`). So overriding has nothing to do with this problem. The question is "when do static initializers run?, when nothing in the class is being executed...despite referencing the sub-class by name, when you call the super/`A`-version of `test`, with `B.test()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Class B` does not implement (aka "hide") the `static test` method, so initial execution begins within `Class A` (hence A-SIB); and then with the `test` method in `A` (hence "A-test").  If you override `test` in `Class B`, you will get A-SIB B-SIB B-test

Comment: You can't override a static method. You can hide it, but it's quite different.

Comment: Sorry .. was using the generic English word "override".  I have adjusted the answer to refer to the Java-specific term.

Answer (score 13):

Here's what [the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1) says about class initialization:

> Initialization of a class consists of executing its static initializers and the initializers for static fields (class variables) declared in the class.
>
> Initialization of an interface consists of executing the initializers for fields (constants) declared in the interface.
>
> Before a class is initialized, its direct superclass must be initialized, but interfaces implemented by the class are not initialized. Similarly, the superinterfaces of an interface are not initialized before the interface is initialized.
>
> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> - T is a class and an instance of T is created.
> - T is a class and a static method declared by T is invoked.
> - A static field declared by T is assigned.
> - A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant variable (§4.12.4).
> - T is a top level class (§7.6), and an assert statement (§14.10) lexically nested within T (§8.1.3) is executed.
>
> A reference to a static field (§8.3.1.1) causes initialization of only the class or interface that actually declares it, even though it might be referred to through the name of a subclass, a subinterface, or a class that implements an interface.

In this case, All you do in C with the class B is call the static method `test()`. But this method is declared in A, not in B. Thus, the JVM doesn't initialize the class B and thus doesn't invoke its static initializer block.

Note that the class B is referenced in C's byte-code and is loaded by the JVM. But it's not initialized. If you delete `B.class` and try to run C, you'll get an exception.